# Do you need a Vignette to travel the roads of Switzerland, and how can I obtain one?

Tags: germany, car-rentals, automobiles, switzerland

To drive on Swiss motorways if I recall correctly one needs a [Vignette](http://www.ezv.admin.ch/zollinfo_privat/04338/04340/index.html?lang=en) based on what I have been reading I should be able to buy it at [various places](http://www.autobahnen.ch/index.php?lg=001&page=014) in the country.

I am renting a car in Frankfurt and my travels will take me through Switzerland for a day or 2 so it begs the question:

1. Do car rental companies in Germany provide a Vignette for the car already?

or

2. Can I buy or rent a Swiss Vignette from them?

Comment: @ptityeti I don't feel like driving slow.

Comment: As stated in the answers below it currently costs 40 Swiss Franc. Luckily the cantons denied an increase to 100.- in 2013, but the issue is still on discussion, so it might get more expensive in the next years...

Comment: Note; if you are in Germany and will be driving to Switzerland through Austria, you need a vignette for Austrian autobahns too. They do them for different lengths of time - 3 months, 12 months -  and if you are just passing through you get one for 10 days. These are sold in the area before the border at filling stations, and there is a station just metres before the border where most people buy both. They accept credit cards and EU banks cards.

Comment: @RedSonja If OP is coming from Frankfurt I highly doubt he will even come close to Austria when driving to Switzerland …

Comment: @Karlson It is not that uncommon that German rental cars have a toll sticker from Austria or Switzerland, not as an offer by the rental company, but bought by a previous customer. Even if it is not guaranteed, I would at lest tell the rental company that you would prefer a car with a Swiss toll sticker when ordering the car and with some luck, they might be able to give you a car, for which the toll is already paid.

Comment: @Karlson regarding speed, Switzerland has *very* strictly enforced speed limits, especially on the motorways with a max of 120km/h. Do not speed in Switzerland unless you intend to pay substantial fines: https://www.ch.ch/en/driving-over-speed-limit/ (on the plus side, they will take accept just about any payment method).

Comment: @Jan Yes, but depends very much where he wants to go. If he wants to go to the eastern part his navigatrix will probably send him through Bregenz and Liechtenstein, much quicker that way.

Comment: You cannot rent it but if you do it carefuly you can remove it from your windshield and resell it ;)

Comment: @RedSonja Austrian vignette will make an interesting different question but if I were to visit the eastern part I would start my journey in Munich (as I've done before).

Comment: @YvesKlett 120 is better than 90 on a 2 lane road.

Comment: sure thing - just to give you a heads-up. For single trips, avoiding motorways can be economic. Switzerland is not that big, and a trip along the countryside can actually be quite pleasing. Most of the time I end up getting a vignette anyway for multiple use. Compared to other swiss prices, this is quite cheap. Try getting a salad, pizza and beer for forty francs, and you will know...

Comment: @YvesKlett I know.  I am actually not traveling through Switzerland for pleasure this time around.  Just need to get in and out.

Comment: You can also avoid the motorways and enjoy the beauties of the mountain passes.

Comment: @VladimirF Not this time around.

Comment: @Karlson just out of interest, how would you get from München to Switzerland without going through Austria? (I ask because I drive that way often).

Comment: @RedSonja Drive to Basel

Comment: @Karlson that's an awfully long way round. Google or a navi will send you via Bregenz, it really is shorter. Still, it depends where in Schweiz you want to go.

Comment: @RedSonja Precisely.  Along with your starting point in Germany too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You do indeed need a yearly vignette to drive on Swiss motorways. It costs CHF 40 and needs to be affixed to the windshield to be valid (in principle, merely having one somewhere in the car isn't enough to avoid a fine). The vignette for a given year is valid from the beginning of December in the year before until the end of January in the year after.

I don't know for sure but I doubt you can buy that vignette from car hire companies as far out as Frankfurt and I would be really surprised if you could rely on a rental having one already (as others have suggested you can always ask or be lucky, but it's not standard).

But you don't need to worry about first entering Switzerland and trying to track down a place that sells it, getting one on the way is really easy. Usually, you can buy the Swiss vignette at the last couple of petrol stations/rest areas in Germany (possibly losing one or two euros on the exchange rate but nothing to worry about if it feels more convenient) and at the border itself, certainly on the motorway (smaller border crossings do not have any customs office/staff nowadays but major crossings still do).

Comment: That's a very *relax*ing answer :)

Comment: You will most likely pay more than necessary if you buy the vignette in Germany, since the retailer will charge you in euro and use a poor exchange rate to convert the price. You can however buy the vignette at all Swiss customs offices and since you will find a customs office at nearly all border crossings, it is not a problem to buy the vignette there and only pay the 'official' price without any surcharges.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo The exact opposite is advertised at the [Royal Dutch Touring Club (ANWB) website](http://www.anwb.nl/vakantie/zwitserland/informatie/tol). Translation: *Border offices do not accept coins. If you pay with euros, change is given in Francs with a poor exchange rate*. **My advice would be to buy a vignette from an ADAC (the German touring club) shop**. Then you don't have to worry about it anymore for the rest of your trip.

Comment: @sanchises It surprises me that Swiss customs accepts euro in cash at all, but why is that an issue? Why can't you pay with Swiss francs (cash) or with card? Buying the vignette from ANWB or ADAC is probably the least attractive option, since you pay 2.95€ postage in addition to the overpriced vignette, in total 41.45€. With the current exchange rate, the real price of the vignette is 36.10€, saving you 5.35€ if you buy it in Switzerland.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo OTOH, we are not talking about a huge difference so my advice would still be to feel free to do whatever feels convenient.

Answer (score 11):

In Germany there are no special vignettes - it's all free. But yes, as already written in the comments, in Switzerland you need a vignette. The vignette costs **40 Swiss Francs** and will be valid for one year. There is only this one version. The vignette is only needed for motorways, not for the rest.

You can buy them at gas stations, or - most often - somewhere at the border. If you enter Switzerland, watch for some "Vignettes here" signs, or just go to the next gas station. The vignette **has to be put onto the front windshield**. If you just have it, but it is not stuck to the windshield, it is not valid.

Comment: It was expensive when I bought it in 2009, I remember on the order of $50. A [quick Google search](http://www.autobahnen.ch/index.php?lg=001&page=014) shows that the price is actually 37 euros.

Comment: @MartinArgerami It feels unfair for tourists who just go there once, perhaps deliberately so, but CHF 40 isn't really expensive. You can easily spend more than that on tolls in a single trip in France or Italy. Meanwhile, a yearly vignette is over EUR 80 in Austria.

Comment: The vignette is not valid for one year, but for 14 specific calendar months: the calendar year printed on the vignette (e.g. 2016), December of the previous year and January in the following year.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Switzerland does not use the euro and the price is 40 Swiss francs.

Comment: @Relaxed: since they charged me that amount for a single 250km trip, I will stay put and say that it is insanely expensive, even more than the Italian tolls.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: fair enough, but the 37 euro figure comes from the official Swiss motorways web site.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Which 'official Swiss motorways web site'?

Comment: My bad. Without looking carefully I thought that [this site](http://www.autobahnen.ch/index.php?lg=001&page=014) was official.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Neither is that an official site, nor does it say that the price is 37 euro.

Comment: Pasted from the site: "40 Swiss francs (ca. 37 Euro)".

Comment: @MartinArgerami Well, if you want a really outrageous example, entering Geneva from France or Basel from Germany through the motorway just to take the first or second exit also costs CHF 40, which is indisputably very very expensive. But CHF 40 for 250 km isn't *insanely* expensive, it's roughly the same price, per km, as what you have to pay between Courmayeur and Ivrea (about 20€ for less than 100 km). For a yearly vignette in one of the most expensive countries in Western Europe, where a meal at McDonalds costs €13-15…

Answer (score 10):

Everthing is clearly explained in the [Swiss Autobahnen site](http://www.autobahnen.ch/index.php?lg=001&page=014) .

The vignette is required for most major highways, and costs 40 swiss francs. In can be bought at "post offices, petrol stations, garages, touring club offices (TCS) and Customs".

The time I used it I had rented a car in Frankfurt. As far as I recall, I got it at the border.

Answer (score 5):

**Edited**

1: check with your car rental company about the vignette. Border areas will most likely provide a car with the vignette already affixed if they know you will be traversing Switzerland.

2: Renting a vignette is not possible. Buying one is simple

**Previously**

In Switzerland you need a vignette to use the motorways.

It costs 40 CHF and is available in numerous places. If you are driving into Switzerland, stop off at the customs and you can buy one there. Check the [Swiss tourist website](https://www.ch.ch/fr/vignette-autoroutiere/) for more information.

Comment: I've read it before asking the question.

Comment: If in doubt. Leave the hire car at the border and rent my driving services for a day or two 8) I could do with a break

Comment: I think 40 CHF will beat what I will have to pay you. ;)

Comment: 8D But I'm more interesting than a vignette (I hope)

Answer (score 3):

Other answers have covered the options of buying a Swiss vignette, however there's one more option you can try.

When you get to the rental agency, ask if they have a car with a Swiss vignette in their inventory. While this may seem far-fetched, I've actually seen rental cars in *Czech Republic* with a valid Swiss vignette. Since they're valid for 14 months and no short-term options exist, any car that's driven into Switzerland in the past year would likely have one stuck on the windshield.

Comment: (+1) I actually edited my answer to mention this as you were writing yours!

Answer (score 3):

Buying a Swiss Vignette is actually very simple and it may be possible to obtain a rental car with Vignette already but usually that will only happen if someone had purchased one when driving to Switzerland.

Having said that to obtain a Vignette all one needs to do is purchase one at the border from the police officer.

[image]

Lanes while crossing the border are divided into 2 lanes left for the through traffic and right for the local or traffic that needs vignettes or have other business at the border.  Driving to the right you will be greeted by a police office who will happily sell you a Vignette for 40CHF or 40 Euro.

Comment: Does the police officer accept card payments?

Comment: Unfortunaltely cash only.

Answer (score 0):

When I last travelled to switzerland by car I was able to buy a Vignette in Frankfurt, at [ADAC](https://www.adac.de/)

Comment: Trying to avoid driving through the city.