# Getting pulled over in Switzerland

Tags: legal, driving, automobiles, switzerland

Since we've been discussing [Swiss Vignette](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69587/do-you-need-a-vignette-to-travel-the-roads-of-switzerland-and-how-can-i-obtain) and steep fines were mentioned for speeding at Switzerland I got to wondering:

In some countries getting out of the car and walking towards police with documents is acceptable.  In the US police office won't take any chances with you getting out of the car and walking toward him.

If I did get pulled over by police in Switzerland (unless of course it's all electronic and all I do is just get mail) what is the procedure for me as a driver?

Comment: I would think "remain in the car with your hands in view" would be fine in any country.

Comment: Since staying in the car would seem to be pretty much always acceptable, while getting out of the car and approaching the officers could, at least in some countries, create a very dangerous and volatile situation, staying in the car is probably a good plan basically anywhere.

Comment: I would never get out and walk back to a car that pulled me over, no matter how official it looks.  I would always wait to see who gets out of that car and then do as they directed.

Comment: You're probably right.  But I would like to be sure.

Comment: On a highway, getting out at the driver's side of the car is a **very** bad idea. Police are aware of this and will guide you to a safe parking spot if necessary.

Comment: "In some countries getting out of the car and walking towards police with documents is acceptable" ... which countries, Karlson ?!?!

Comment: @JoeBlow Ukraine

Comment: It is common to remain seated with the engine shut off and  hands on the wheel, however that's not a law; the fact that Swiss police in 2015 have used their guns a [a grand 15 times](http://www.srf.ch/news/schweiz/schweizer-polizei-greift-weniger-haeufig-zum-taser) tells you that they are not easily provoked. Frankly it is, with the going rate for even minor offenses, much more likely that they will fine you to death.

Comment: @EikePierstorff If that is the procedure you should put this as an answer.

Comment: There is no procedure, as far as the law is concerned you might as well tapdance. You have to understand that for a Swiss/Austrian/German citizen the idea that the police might shoot you in a traffic control seems utterly quaint even now. Preemptive meekness has the advantage that it will speed things up, but it is not mandatory.

Comment: @EikePierstorff As I said this might as well be an answer.

Comment: As a side note, many, many years ago, when I was pulled over by the police in the USA for the first time (Massachusetts, if I remember correctly), I didn't know that I was supposed to sit in the car, so I got out and started walking toward the police car that was behind mine.  The officer didn't even put his hand on the holster - just told me to "please return to your vehicle, sir".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are pulled over, they will either pull you over on the spot, or escort you to a safe place (e.g. parking lot if you are pulled over on a highway).

Shut down your engine, roll down your window, keep your hands visible. The officer will approach you, and will provide you with further instructions.

This goes for any country. If they want you to do something, they will ask/order you to. In general, police in Europe isn't as trigger happy as the US police. Only if you are trying to escape, cause some major traffic accidents, and try to run over cops, they might shoot at you. If you do something they don't like, they'll ask you to ("please remain in your car", "please shut down your engine", ...). Just follow up their orders and you'll be fine.

Comment: I have been pulled over in Switzerland multiple times and that is exactly what I did. The Swiss police force is not trigger happy at all, in 2015 they discharged their weapons a total of 15 times.