# Toll roads in Switzerland

Tags: switzerland, tolls

I will be driving from Geneva to Lyon this week (planning on taking [this route](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/Geneva,+Switzerland/Lyon,+France/@45.9314905,5.2835734,10z/am=t/data=!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x478c650693d0e2eb:0xa0b695357b0bbc39!2m2!1d6.1431577!2d46.2043907!1m5!1m1!1s0x47f4ea516ae88797:0x408ab2ae4bb21f0!2m2!1d4.835659!2d45.764043!3e0)). If I recall correctly, the toll roads in France I paid by card but is this the same case with Switzerland? I don't plan on taking any Swiss money with me and really don't want to be stuck in a situation where I'm unable to pay.

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69587/do-you-need-a-vignette-to-travel-the-roads-of-switzerland-and-how-can-i-obtain

Comment: @CMaster Then I guess my question is, will my rental car already have a vignette?

Comment: That would be a seperate question, but one perhaps best answered by your hire care company. Given you plan to have no swiss cash, will you actually be leaving Geneva Airport, not Geneva city? In which case, French side or Swiss side?

Comment: @CMaster Geneva airport..I didn't even know there were different sides. I am woefully under-prepared for this trip ha. Thank you!

Comment: @ediblecode yes, the Geneva airport is literally right on the Swiss/French border.

Comment: Some rental car companies are present with French subsidiaries at the Geneva airport. If you want to return the car in France this might be cheaper than hiring from a Swiss subsidiary, who will charge you extra fees for bringing the car back to Switzerland. A French car however most likely won't have a Swiss vignette, but even if you go downtown you eventually could bypass toll roads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switzerland toll roads work with an annual sticker, which is quite expensive for one trip.
They do not have a per-use system; and you need to buy the sticker ahead of entering the country.

Comment: Generally speaking, the _vignette_, which costs around 30-40 €, is not particularly expensive, even for one trip (and certainly not by Swiss standards). In France or Italy you can spend about the same amount of money in a one-day trip through the highways. Moreover, in Switzerland, traffic on local roads is quite slow. For the OP's case, however, I agree that the segment in Switzerland is really too short to buy the vignette.